# Parse Push Notification Payload nil in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications

Parameters: iOS 9.1, iphone 5S, xcode 7.1, Swift 2, Parse SDK 1.9.0

I am trying to capture push notification messages sent via Parse for all states of the receiving device (i.e. foreground/background/not loaded/device turned off).  For all cases, my device receives the push notifications but in some cases the payload/userInfo dictionary does not arrive.

For situations where:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

is called (e.g. app in foreground) in the AppDelegate, the userInfo dictionary is received correctly and I can save the message, issue a notification & display it in an appropriate ViewController.

However, where

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

is called in the AppDelegate (e.g. if device is turned off and the push notification banner is "swiped" to open the App), the payload obtained from the statement:

```
if let notificationPayload:NSDictionary = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary
```

is always nil and I cannot complete the same actions as above.

The statements that generate the push are:

```
push.setData(["alert" : message, "badge": "Increment", "content-available": NSNumber(integer: 1)])
push.sendPushInBackground()
```

where message is a String containing the message to be displayed.

I have read numerous posts on SO, etc. & tried various ways to solve this but cannot find a solution.  Any ideas/assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I can post more code if necessary but I am basically following the standard approach from Parse examples & other SO posts.

RB

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without seeing the rest of the code, but my guess is that something has gone awry when registering for notifications. If the notification registration is not done correctly then the app will disregard the payload

Comment: Russell.  Thx. for your reply.  I have done more experimenting/reading & have a bit better understanding of the behaviour.  I think it derives from the fact that I was always force killing the app between tests combined with the fact that it is still receiving silent pushes.  It seems to act as if the app icon was used to open the app, i.e. the payload is intentionally set to nil.  If I don't force kill the app, I get the payload (thru didReceiveRemoteNotification I believe) when the device is reactivated. Now all I need to do is to handle the case where the app icon actually is pressed.